# how do I make the nvm-managed version of node the default one for all processes?

Tags: iterm2

I use nvm to manage node. However, every new terminal I create uses the wrong version. They use the one in `/usr/local/bin/node`, which is where homebrew put node. That's node v5.

Using nvm, I've installed v12. I've tried to set both the system and default aliases to point to v12, although the UI suggests these attempts are failing silently in some way. (The colors of the entries makes it look like the references are broken.) However, when I manually `nvm use default`, nvm switches me to v12.

I don't want to have to manually set the node version in every terminal I create.

One solution would be to add `nvm use default` to my `~/.bash_profile`. I dno't have a problem doing that, but I also want to make sure that every other process on my machine uses the nvm-managed nodes instead of the ancient homebrew-installed one. I fear that editing `~/.bash_profile` will fail to impact those other cases.

I'm using nvm v0.34.0 and iTerm2 (build 3.1.5) on MacOS

Here's output from a fresh terminal demonstrating the version and location before and after using nvm:

```
Last login: Sat Oct 19 12:52:31 on ttys000
[Sat 13:13:56] ~ $ node --version
v5.10.1
[Sat 13:14:02] ~ $ which node
/usr/local/bin/node
[Sat 13:14:03] ~ $ nvm use default
Now using node v12.12.0 (npm v6.11.3)
[Sat 13:14:07] ~ $ node --version
v12.12.0
[Sat 13:14:09] ~ $ which node
/Users/tpr/.nvm/versions/node/v12.12.0/bin/node
```